# php unlink continuously

Tags: php, file, queue, delete-file, unlink

I am experimenting with php `unlink()`, what I want to do is run a php script that deletes files created every few minutes after parsing them. I can do that with a cron or as continuously running the file that handles parse/delete on the background. What I want to ask is will deleting files every few minutes, cause problems to my web server or is there any performance downgrade when doing this or some other negative effect I can't think of?

Also how can I create a queue of files to process and dispose with php? Is that any different that what I described above?

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am a bit lost on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the approach would be based on some variables...

1. Are you wanting to do this for a user-session?
2. Are you wanting to do it strictly based on time?
3. The images you are creating, are they stored or referenced globally?
4. Are these images being used for any extended period of time, does that time change anything?

The easiest solution, in my opinion would be to create a cron job.  If you can store the image and creation date (db or session), when your cron runs it can evaluate creation time vs script run-time and execute appropriately.

You have a lot of other options, but I think it comes down to the variables listed.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Regarding your questions -> 1. No the process will run on the background (both generating and parsing/deleting files) independently of any user sessions
2. Yes it should be based on time every 5 or 10 mins
3. they are stored
4.They are only used for parsing (a few milliseconds i guess) and then they are not required

Comment: In that case, I would go with the cron job.  Unless your server is tight on space, I would run the cron every hour or so (or even longer), to keep loads down (not sure what kind of traffic you're dealing with). Then you can just unlink all files created more than 3-5 minutes from the script running. -Just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks True North Creative. So basically as i understand it doesn't matter how i do the the unlinking (cron or otherwise) the load on the server is not significant from this operation (delete) even if it runs continuously ( say delete is performed 2wice a day), right? Also is it better to do a group delete once a day or at smaller intervals. Please bear in mind that files are created every 5 mins so once a day, for example, is a bulk delete of about 300 files about 1mb each. Thanks

Comment: If diskspace isn't an issue, then running that once (or twice) a day would be fine, and ideal.  It will keep resources to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the files will probably produce a higher load than deleting them afterwards. Without knowing more about what your parse processing and your server environment it will be impossible to say whether there will be any noticeable performance degradation.

I would create a MySQL table to hold a list of files to process. You can then add entries to the table from one script and remove them after parsing/deleting them.

Comment: Parsing is just a substr_count, environment Virtual Dedicated Linux server.